# Is my PC visible or accessible to other PCs if I have connected to the internet through PPPoE?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, lan

Once I had subscribed to an ISP who had provided me some IP addresses to connect to the internet. However, when I went into the Networks window, it displayed several other computer names that never knew. [Similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw1zB.jpg). I was worried back then regarding the privacy whether those PC users can get into my PC and get access of my files, or spread virus or malware intentionally or unintentionally.

Now, I would like know more whether it possible get access to my PC by other subscribers of my ISP if I am connecting to the internet using PPPoE (username and password) without using any home Wi-Fi router. By that, I meant I am not using any home router, I will be connecting the Ethernet cable directly into my PC and dial up a connection using the ISP provided username and password.

Comment: There are honestly too many questions here. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Use the search bar at the top of the page and show us what your understanding is. Be concise and specific in your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I have reduced the number of questions and tried pin pointed to the actual question.

Comment: Is this a problem you currently have?  Discoverable devices being listed is perfectly normal, if you have not enabled file sharing, then those devices on the network cannot access your files.

Comment: I had this issue several years back, when the ISP used ip addresses to connect my pc to the internet. However, I am just concerned about personal privacy. So, I would like to learn more.

Comment: Is there some specific issue regarding malware that you noticed ? A general question about privacy is meaningless. Try to rephrase it with a specific concern.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the ISP sets up it's network so the connected subscribers are shielded from each other. But that depends on the ISP so you will have to ask your ISP to make sure.

Other then that, if you don't have a public IP address or a NAT IP address that has port forward enabled you should be fine. If not your PC can be accessed from the internet, unless you block your ports via a firewall or disable the tasks listening on those ports.